# Sort em array com duas dimensões no VBA

Tags: array, vba, classificação

Tenho uma *array* dinâmica de duas dimensões com:

Datas de nascimento na primeira dimensão (coluna) e nomes na segunda dimensão:

> Exemplo:
>    MinhaArray(0,0) = "01/05/1990"
>    MinhaArray(1,0) =
>   "Luisa Silva"

Eu gostaria de um método *sort* que eu pudesse usar a primeira coluna (data) como parâmetro, mas que quando fosse movida trouxesse junto a posição da segunda coluna.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?